# Error when running python read.py and write.py (MFRC552) library

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, rfid

so im getting an error while setting up my RFID552 on RP 4B

i downloaded this library https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python

When I run the Read.py, i get an error saying error in line 33 which is     `print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."`

same with write.py both errors points to `"`

this the full read.py code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MFRC522
import signal

continue_reading = True

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
    continue_reading = False
    GPIO.cleanup()

# Hook the SIGINT
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

# Create an object of the class MFRC522
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

# Welcome message
print "Welcome to the MFRC522 data read example"
print "Press Ctrl-C to stop."

# This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID and authenticate
while continue_reading:
    
    # Scan for cards    
    (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQIDL)

    # If a card is found
    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
        print "Card detected"
    
    # Get the UID of the card
    (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

    # If we have the UID, continue
    if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:

        # Print UID
        print "Card read UID: %s,%s,%s,%s" % (uid[0], uid[1], uid[2], uid[3])
    
        # This is the default key for authentication
        key = [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF]
        
        # Select the scanned tag
        MIFAREReader.MFRC522_SelectTag(uid)

        # Authenticate
        status = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Auth(MIFAREReader.PICC_AUTHENT1A, 8, key, uid)

        # Check if authenticated
        if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
            MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(8)
            MIFAREReader.MFRC522_StopCrypto1()
        else:
            print "Authentication error"
```

Comment: please, copy the whole error message and paste it into your question ... format it as code

Answer (score 0):

That is ancient python2 code - which was phased out in 2020 and hasn't been supported for years.

No recent Raspberry Pi OS (or other Linux OS) includes python2.

It may work if you convert print statements to functions but I suggest you find more recent code.